# str_replace on ® symbol does not work in PHP

Tags: php, string, str-replace

Says it all in the title really. The following code always returns false:

```
$product = str_replace('®', '', $product);
```

I have also tried searching for the html entities for the ® symbol.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: `$product = html_entity_decode(str_replace('&reg;', '', htmlentities($product)));`

Comment: @hd You ought to post that as an answer

Comment: `®` is not a string like this, it has the defination `&reg;` so you need to replace `&reg;`

Comment: heh, good idea @AmericanUmlaut

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of file encoding, you will have to decode the symbol to it's entity value (`&reg;`)

```
$product = html_entity_decode(str_replace('&reg;', '', htmlentities($product)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing HD-'s answer is right but I'm thinking that this string with special characters are coming from a database and you don't have a quick way to transform the ® sign to its HTML representation `&reg`;

The problem you are getting may be originated by the fact that the database connection is using an encoding other than the encoding used by your php script.

If your PHP script is being saved in UTF-8, try the code below:

```
$product = str_replace('®', '', utf8_encode($product));
```